# Excel custom number format complex conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, number-formatting, excel-2013

I need following:

My numbers are to be divided by 1000 and rounded, negative in brackets, zeroes as "-":

```
  1500 ->  2
  499  ->  -
  0    ->  -
 -499  ->  -
 -1500 -> (2)
```

I cannot find how to transform values [-499;499] to "-", everything else is fine.

Currently (simplified) I have smth like this: 
`"#,##0, ;(#,##0,);- "`

It displays my numbers as:

```
  1500 ->  2
  499  ->  0 (I need "-" here)
  0    ->  -
 -499  -> (0)(I need "-" here)
 -1500 -> (2)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: do you like it using formula or just formatting

Comment: Try `[>=500]#,##0, ;[<=-500](#,##0,);-;[color3]@` I've added red font for any rogue text values so that you can quickly locate them.

Comment: @yass only formatting

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution:

```
 [>=500]_(* #,##0,_);[<=-500]_(* (#,##0,);_(* #,_ "-"_);_(@_)
```

Displays my numbers as:

```
 1500       ->  2
 499        ->  -
 0          ->  -
-499        ->  -
-1500       -> (2)
 blank cell -> blank cell
 text       -> text
```

Main problem was how to display -499 as "-"

as Jeeped posted

```
  [>=500]#,##0, ;[<=-500](#,##0,);-;[color3]@
```

did this:

```
 1500       ->  2
 499        ->  -
 0          ->  -
-499        ->  -- (here was the problem)
-1500       -> (2)
 blank cell -> blank cell
 text       -> text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula and formatting, in B1:

```
=IF(ROUND(A1/1000,0)<>0,ROUND(A1/1000,0),"-")
```

- Number
- Format Cells
- Number (under category)
- Choose (123) and 0 for decimal places
- Ok

And drag it down

**Another way:**
 Use the formula in B1:

```
=ROUND(A1/1000,0)
```

Drag it down, select the result and Custom Format with:

`0;(0);-`

- Number
- Format Cells
- Custom (under category)
- Write in the Box: `0;(0);-`
- Ok

Comment: I need to achieve this only via formatting - I have a lot of cells that contain formulas already, and they have to be formatted. (using formula in b1 also not acceptable)

Comment: Use the custom format 0;(0);- as written in the second part of my answer